# "A better future tomorrow" vs "a better tomorrow"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-meaning, definite-article, phrases

I need to write something like this on a poster:

Save (**the?**) Environment Today

For a Better (Future) Tomorrow

Basically I want to say: Save environment (resources) today so that we can live better tomorrow or something like that, as it is World Environment Day today.

Is **future** unnecessary or important or would have a different meaning here?

Also, do I need to put a **the** before Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need the "the" before "environment," because "environment" is a countable noun, and so you want to specify which environment you're talking about; "the environment" typically refers to the entire planet and/or all habitable areas.

No, you do not want to use the word future, because you're using the fairly standard "today/tomorrow" poetic license, where "today" means "currently/the current age" and "tomorrow" means "the time/age that follows". You could substitute "today" and "tomorrow" for the same effect as "now" and "future":

> Save the Environment Now/Today
>
> For a Better Future/Tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

How environment becomes countable? I think it is neuter gender. It it is proper noun. Definite article the is used before proper nouns. So the environment is correct.

Comment: Please do not repeat answers